# Why does these confocal images show concentric circles?

Tags: microscopy, fluorescent-microscopy

I recently got this confocal microscopic image from my microscopy facility. I am unable to understand why these concentric circles are there. They look like out of focal fringes in conventional microscopy, but this is from a confocal as I mentioned. (It is only appearing in red channel, if that provides a hint.)

They are present in several images toa varying extent.

[image: concentric confocal features]

Comment: Welcome user 80133. Could you provide a few more details such as the subject, medium and the approximate magnification or some other idea of scale. It seems like some artifact of refraction due to droplet surrounding the subject, but we'd nee more details.

Comment: “Does this” or “Do these”. A basic feature of English grammar is number agreement between subject and verb.